# What does Ruby HTTP's read_status_line do?

Tags: ruby, http, request, response

I am currently working on some POST requests for my Ruby application, and I received an error related to `wrong status line`. Looking at the documentation, the exception would be thrown if the following regex is matched:

```
def read_status_line(sock)
  str = sock.readline
  m = /\AHTTP(?:\/(\d+\.\d+))?\s+(\d\d\d)(?:\s+(.*))?\z/in.match(str) or
    raise Net::HTTPBadResponse, "wrong status line: #{str.dump}"
  m.captures
end
```

[source](https://gemfury.com/gitshiva/deb:ruby/-/content/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb)

I'm curious what the regex is actually trying to match?

```
/\AHTTP(?:\/(\d+\.\d+))?\s+(\d\d\d)(?:\s+(.*))?\z/in.match(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the HTTP response header straight from [section 6 of RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6):

```
Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
```

In other words, something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Or maybe:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
```

Comment: Ohh! I'm inspecting `sock.readline`, and I am getting the following result `"HTTP/1.1 1 CUSTOM"` which does not match that regex.

Comment: Status codes should be, as per the spec, in the form of NNN, or `\d\d\d` in regular expression speak. `1` is invalid. You're dealing with a bad implementation of HTTP. If you're really stuck and need this code to just deal with that horribly broken server, maybe patch out this method with one that tests vs. `\d+` instead. Ugly, but sometimes necessary.

Comment: Okay thank you. Now I have to figure out why I am getting `HTTP/1.1 1 CUSTOM`. Would you have any ideas?

Comment: 99% chance it's someone's wonkball non-compliant HTTP server code they slammed out on a Friday before heading out to tacos and drinks. What is the `Server:` identifier in the response? You can get that kind of data with a tool like `curl` or the inspector in Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a response because this exception gets thrown before I can get to the response part. This is the `request.to_hash`: `{"content-type"=>["application/json"], "accept-encoding"=>["gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3"], "accept"=>["*/*"], "user-agent"=>["Ruby"]}`

Comment: You'll have to use another tool, or possibly even something more primitive like plain TCP sockets. The `Server:` header in the response should identify it. The request is irrelevant.

Comment: What other tools do you recommend that will let me see the headers in my response?

Comment: `curl`, `telnet`, any browser with a Network Inspector (e.g. Chrome)... It's a long list. Even changing that to first line to `p sock.read` could give you all the details you need.